# Out of memory when adding custom markers with image to Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I would like my markers to be with an image which I download with Volley. It works as to what it should be looking like. The problem is that when I click on group of pins (made with Cluster Manager) the app becomes very unresponsive and crashes with Out of memory message. Here is my code:

```
    class MyClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MarkerItem> {

        Context currentContext;

        public MyClusterRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map,
                                 ClusterManager<MarkerItem> clusterManager) {
            super(context, map, clusterManager);

            currentContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MarkerItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {

            super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onClusterItemRendered(MarkerItem clusterItem, Marker marker) {

            super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker);

            createMarker(clusterItem, marker);
        }

        private void createMarker(MarkerItem clusterItem, final Marker marker) {

            ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(clusterItem.getImageUrl(), new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {

                public void onResponse(Bitmap responseBitMap) {

                    // set for small marker
                    int radius = 160;
                    int stroke = 6;
                    double verticalAnchor = 0.944f;


                    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) radius, (int) radius + 25, conf);
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

                    // creates a centered bitmap of the desired size
                    responseBitMap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(responseBitMap, (int) radius - stroke, (int) radius - stroke, ThumbnailUtils.OPTIONS_RECYCLE_INPUT);
                    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(responseBitMap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                    paint.setColor(0xff464646);
                    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

                    // the triangle laid under the circle
                    int pointedness = 20;
                    Path path = new Path();
                    path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
                    path.moveTo(radius / 2, radius + 15);
                    path.lineTo(radius / 2 + pointedness, radius - 10);
                    path.lineTo(radius / 2 - pointedness, radius - 10);
                    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

                    // gray circle background
                    RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, radius, radius);
                    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius / 2, radius / 2, paint);

                    // circle photo
                    paint.setShader(shader);
                    rect = new RectF(stroke, stroke, radius - stroke, radius - stroke);
                    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, (radius - stroke) / 2, (radius - stroke) / 2, paint);

                    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp));
                }
            }, 100, 100, null, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Log.i("Sharing", "Error");
                }
            });

            request.setShouldCache(true);

            Volley.newRequestQueue(currentContext).add(request);
        } 
}
```

And here is the error message:

> W/art: Suspending all threads took: 21.942ms
>   W/libc: pthread_create failed: couldn't allocate 1064960-byte stack: Out of memory
>   E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again"

[image]

Comment: Hmm. That's strange.. I haven't experience that before. Have you considered using Picasso instead of a Volley request?

Comment: No, I haven't tried because we use Volley on several other places in the code without any significant problems. Also the images should be cached because before that I make the same request in another Fragment.

Comment: I have updated the question with something that I noticed few minutes ago. The app crashes little after I click on group of pins if that is something useful for finding the problem.

Comment: The only thing that can possibly lead to this are the images loaded. I think you should start to get comfortable with [memory analysis](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html)

Comment: I definitely will read this. Thank you!